# Заголовочные файлы Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Что нужно поставить, что бы получить доступ к заголовочным файлам?

Гугл говорит, что нужно поставить SKD и они должны лежать тут:

> %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\

На сколько я знаю, SDK очень много. Что конкретно нужно поставить?

Comment: А какой именно SDK вам нужен?

Comment: Ставьте 2017 студию и используйте SDK устанавливаемый с ней в комплекте по-умолчанию.

Comment: @VTT, Вроде, поставил. Очевидно, что нужно какой-то пакет доустановить, но не знаю какой.

Comment: При выборе средств разработки C++ ставится SDK 10.0.16299.0